# $E(\log X)$ is finite, but $E(X^\alpha) = \infty$ for all $\alpha >0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to think of a random variable $X$ taking values in $1,2,\dots$ such that $E(\log X)$ is finite, but $E(X^\alpha) = \infty$ for all $\alpha >0$.

I tried the pmf $P(X = k) \propto \frac{1}{k \log(k)}$ but then realised that this is not summable. Does such a random variable exist ?

Comment: $P(X=k)=\frac c {k (\log k)^{3}}$

Comment: @SangchulLee Fair enough - I have deleted my comment, though I suspect you need to start the sum at $k=2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_k:=\mathbb P(X=k), k\geqslant 1$.
Since $\mathbb E(g(X))=\sum_{k=1}^\infty g(k)\mathbb P(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty g(k)p_k$, we have to find $p_k$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\log k< \infty$ and for each $\alpha>0$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k k^\alpha=\infty$.

Taking something like $p_k=ck^{-\beta}$ will not work because we should have $\beta>1$ for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\log k< \infty$ to be satisfied but then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k k^\alpha$ would be finite for $\alpha$ such that $\beta-\alpha>1$.
This leads to the example given by geetha290krm, namely, $p_k=c/(k\log k)^3$ for $k\geqslant 2$, where $c$ is such that $\sum_{k\geqslant 2}c/(k\log k)^3=1$.

Alternatively, we can take $p_{2^N}=a_N$ and $p_k=0$ if $k$ does not have the form $2^N$ for some integer $N$. The conditions we want for $a_N$ are
$\sum_{N\geqslant 0}a_N N<\infty$ and $\sum_{N\geqslant 0}a_N2^{N\alpha}=\infty$ for each positive $\alpha$ hence $a_N=c(N+1)^{-3}$ does the job.